# Recurring payment never billed

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Ok, my problem sums up in 3 things:

1. I created a recurring profile using the NVP API and my sandbox account and the informations on the profile are OK:
   [image]
2. I'm never billed and the Next Billing Date never changes. It is April 28, 2016 at the moment I'm writing.
3. There is no informations about this problem on forums, and I'm confident in my Google Search skills.

Why in the world is my subscription never billed?

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  There was an issue with delays in the PayPal Sandbox.  I have looked up the profile and it appears to have billed twice so far.

Comment: I eventually just blindly decided to switch to Live mode, assuming that since there is a long history of issues with Sandbox mode, Live mode would be ok, and it was the case. It was 0% of success for Sandbox and 100% of success for Live mode.